# Imageoverlay draws over Text

Tags: css

Hey I have a little problem with an image overlay, but first of all the complete story. I'm currently creating an artists one-page homepage with an parallax effect based on bootstrap. I used this tutorial for creating a basic template: http://www.script-tutorials.com/bootstrap-one-page-template-with-parallax-effect/.
That looks quite nice:
[image]

But my picture doesn't look sooo nice (yeah it have been taken with an nexus 5 at a festival and I didn't find anything free). So i decided to make an overlay with a little strip pattern (and because I think that looks really cool):

**HTML:**

```
<section id="start">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="text-vcenter">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h3>at the homepage of %NAME%</h3>
        <a href="#welcome" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Continue</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.overlay
{
    background: url('../images/overlay.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#start
{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: url('../images/backgrounds/home.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

overlay.png is a little 3x3 picture:

[image]

**Result:**
[image]

The background image looks really cool now (you may not see that in the picture, because it gets recompressed), but the stripes overlays over the text..

But WHY? I have seen much other websites, who use similar code and there is no problem with that...

And does anyone know a website with free overlaying images (like such stripes, or i have also seen an animated noise image)?

**EDIT:** Now i figured out a way to do that with z-index, but it isn't very nice... If I add z-index -10 to the picture and z-index -5 to the overlay it doesn't overwrite the text (a normal z-index with positive numbers doesn't work :/)

Comment: @JakubMichálek already done, nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

z-index on the div contain your text needs to be set higher than your div contain the strip overlay. Or change aplha, in rgba(number,number,number,alpha) to set transparency.

Comment: z-index only works with negative numbers and I think this is not a good solution.

Comment: `z-index` is for positioning things in 3d space which you should not be using for a layout like this. It’s a complex solution to a very simple problem. If you use `z-index`, you’ll find it is difficult for you and others to make changes to this UI down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use `z-index` here. The correct solution is to put the background on the parent container of which your “Welcome” text elements and button are children.

Example: http://jsbin.com/gexosa/1/edit